# Interview: practical uses of assign-by-reference (as opposed to pass-by-reference)

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, assign

I once landed an interview and was asked what the purpose of assigning a variable by reference would be (as in the following case):

```
int i = 0;

int &j = i;
```

My answer was that C++ references work like C pointers, but cannot assume the NULL value, they must always point to a concrete object in memory. Of course, the syntax is different when using references (no need for the pointer indirection operator, and object properties will be accessed via the dot (.) rather than the arrow (->) operator). Perhaps the most important difference, is that unlike with pointers, where you can make a pointer point to something different (even after it was pointing to the same thing as another pointer), with references, if one reference is updated, then the other references which pointed to the same thing are also updated to point to the very same object.

But then I went on to say that the above use of references is pretty useless (and perhaps this is where I went wrong), because I couldn't see a practical advantage to assigning by reference: since both references end up pointing to the same thing, you could easily do with one reference, and couldn't think of a case where this wouldn't be the case. I went on to explain that references are useful as pass-by-reference function parameters, but not in assignments. But the interviewer said they assign by reference in their code all the time, and flunked me (I then went on to work for a company that this company was a client of, but that's besides the point).

Anyways, several years later, I would like to know where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: "if one reference is updated, then the other references which pointed to the same thing are also updated to point to the very same object." I wonder where you got that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, I'd hope for that company's sake that wasn't the ONLY reason they didn't hire you, since it's a petty detail (and no, you don't really know exactly why a company doesn't hire you).

As touched on in the comment, references NEVER change what they refer to within their lifetime. Once set, a reference refers to that same location, until it "dies".

Now, references are quite useful to simplify an expression. Say we have a class or structure with a fair amount of complicated content. Say something like this:

```
struct A
{
    int x, y, z;
};

struct B
{
    A arr[100];
};

class C
{
 public:
    void func();
    B* list[20];
};

void C::func()
{
    ... 
    if (list[i]->arr[j].x == 4 && list[i]->arr[j].y == 5 &&
        (list[i]->arr[j].z < 10 || list[i]->arr[j].z > 90))
    {
       ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

That's a lot of repeats of `list[i]->arr[j]` in there. So we could rewrite it using a reference:

```
void C::func()
{
    ... 
    A &cur = list[i]->arr[j];
    if (cur.x == 4 && cur.y == 5 &&
        (cur.z < 10 || cur.z > 90))
    {
       ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

The above code assumes `do stuff` is actually mofidying the `cur` element in some way, if not, you should probably use `const A &cur =...` instead.

I use this technique quite a bit to make it clearer and less repetitive.

Comment: Exactly the same could have done with a pointer, except that using a reference you have a slight tiny few less characters to type, and a reference is thus preferable in these cases. Well, at least I'm satisfied that I wasn't missing much in my interview. Regards.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can almost always do the same thing with pointers and references. Some things can't be done with references (such as re-assigning it to point at something else).

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case of assigning a reference to a local variable of primitive type in the same scope, the assignment is very much useless: there is nothing you can do using `j` that you could not do using `i`. There are several mildly negative consequences to it, too, because the readability would suffer, and the optimizer may get confused.

Here is one legitimate use of assigning a reference:

```
class demo {
private:
    map<int,string> cache;
    string read_resource(int id) {
        string resource_string;
        ... // Lengthy process for getting a non-empty resource string
        return resource_string;
    }
public:
    string& get_by_id(int id) {
        // Here is a nice trick
        string &res = cache[id];
        if (res.size() == 0) {
            // Assigning res modifies the string in the map
            res = read_resource(id);
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Above, variable `res` of reference type refers to an element of the map that is either retrieved, or created new. If the string is created new, the code calls the "real" getter, and assigns its result to `res`. This automatically updates the cache, too, saving us another lookup in the `cache` map.

Comment: OK, so slightly less typing and a slight compiler optimization which the compiler could carry out anyways on its own. So, basically, it's only useful to avoid writing long chains of stringed properties and array element accesses. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson It's more than "less typing", though: replacing `res = read_resource(id);` with `cache[id] = read_resource(id);` avoids a second `Log(N)` lookup on the `map`, which is important.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but my comment about compiler optimization refers to the fact that compiled code does not always correspond to what you type. If the compiler sees that `cache[id]` is being referenced several time, it will optimize the code and rewrite it so that a reference to `cache[id]` is created and other `cache[id]` variables are replaced by such reference. Then the code is compiled, producing the same result.

Comment: @JohnSonderson Compilers are not allowed to optimize out function calls. Think about it: what if the map is accessed concurrently, and there is a change done to the map between the two accesses? Compilers have no way of knowing it; programmers do. Hence, adding a reference manually is the only way to avoid the second function call.

Comment: I guess a compiler cannot figure out if a piece of code is to be used in as part of a multithreaded solution, and C++11 now has a `<thread>` include file and associated function calls. Thank you for pointing this out.